# React and React Hooks: Using an onClick function in a child to fire a function of a parent wrapping component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, higher-order-components

I have a wrapper component that conditionally renders it's children based on it's own state (`isDeleted`). Basically I have a 'delete-able item' component where if a button is clicked to delete, the item itself will be removed from the DOM (by returning an empty ReactNode i.e. <></>). The problem is, I can't figure out how to have the button click event, which appears as a child of the wrapper, to be passed INTO the wrapped component itself:

```js
export default function App() {
    return (
        <DeleteableItemComponent>
            {/* lots of other markup here */}
            <button onClick={triggerFunctionInsideDeletableItemComponent}>
        </DeleteableItemComponent>
    )
}
```

and the most basic version of my delete-able item component:

```js
export default function DeleteableItemComponent() {
    const [isDeleted, setIsDeleted] = useState(false);

    const functionIWantToFire = () => {
        // call API here to delete the item serverside; when successful, 'delete' on frontend
        setIsDeleted(true)
    }

    if (isDeleted) {
        return <></>
    }

    return <>{children}</>
}
```

So put very simply, I just want to call the `functionIWantToFire` from the button `onClick` callback.

How can this be done properly via hooks? I've thought of using the context API but I've never seen it used to trigger function firing, only for setting values, and in this case I want to fire the event itself, not communicate specific values to the wrapper component. I also can't do it correctly through just passing a boolean prop, because then I can only set it once i.e. from `false` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `React.cloneElement` API to pass props to your child while iterating through it using `React.children.map`.

```
React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
   return React.cloneElement(child, { /* .. props here */ });
});
```

A simple example would be.
You could check the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zwnmqd)

```
function App() {
  return (
   <Delete>
      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
   </Delete>
  );
}

function Delete({ children }) {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(0);

  const inc = () => setClicked(clicked + 1);
  const dec = () => setClicked(clicked - 1);

  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, { inc, clicked, dec });
  });
}


function Child1(props) {
  return ( 
    <div>
      <p>{props.clicked}</p>
      <button onClick={props.inc}>Inc</button>
    </div>
  )
}

function Child2(props) {
  return ( 
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.dec}>Dec</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```